# Memory allocation operators and expressions

Tags: c++

In C++, is 'new' an operator or an expression or some kind of keyword? a similar question that comes in mind is, should i call '=' an operator or expression?

Comment: Vote to close: Not really a programming question.

Comment: @Oli, how so?  It's a specific, answerable question about the semantics of a programming language.

Comment: A small problem with this question is that it assumes that keywords can't be expressions. `this` is a clear counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new is operator. You can overload it and write your own version of it. Also I think that = is operator. Expression is more complex thing which consist of operators, variables, function calls etc. And please try to get C++ language standard. It must describe all things you mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps you could quote something from the standard to support *your* answer.

Comment: I also hear the term assignment expressions, Can you provide some examples? thanks.

Comment: That's not actually correct. `new` is most commonly encountered in the new *expression*.

Answer (score 6):

C++ separates the notion of memory allocation and object lifetime. This is a new feature compared to C, since in C an object was equivalent to its memory representation (which is called "POD" in C++).

An object begins its life when a constructor has completed, and its life ends when the destructor has completed. For an object of dynamic storage duration, the life cycle thus consists of four key milestones:

1. Memory allocation.
2. Object construction.
3. Object destruction.
4. Memory deallocation.

The standard way in C++ to allocate memory dynamically is with the global `::operator new()`, and deallocation with `::operator delete()`. However, to **construct** an object there is only one method: A *new expression*:

```
T * p = new T;
```

This most common form of the new expression does allocation and construction in one step. It is equivalent to the broken down version:

```
void * addr = ::operator new(sizeof(T));
T * p = new (addr) T;  // placement-new
```

Similarly, the *delete expression* `delete p;` first calls the destructor and then releases memory. It is equivalent to this:

```
p->~T();
::operator delete(addr);
```

Thus, the *default* new and delete expressions perform memory allocation and object construction in one wash. All *other* forms of the new expression, collectively called "placement new", call a corresponding placement-new *operator* to allocate memory before constructing the object. However, there is no matching "placement delete expression", and all dynamic objects created with placement-new have to be destroyed manually with `p->~T();`.

In summary, it is very important to distinguish the *new expression* from the *operator new*. This is really at the heart of memory management in C++.

Answer (score 3):

It's all of those.

2.13 Table 4 explicitly lists `new` as a keyword.

5.3.4 Introduces the *`new-expression`*. This is an expression such as `new int(5)` which uses the `new` keyword, a type and an initial value.

5.3.4/8 Then states that `operator new` is called to allocate memory for the object created by the *new-expression*

`=` works quite the same. Each class has an `operator=` (unless explicitly deleted), which is used in assignment expressions. We usually call `a=5;` just an assignment, even when it's technically "an expression statement containing an assignment expression."